# ES6 destruct in import statement

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there any way of writing this code:

```
import {o} from 'lib'
let {a, b} = o
```

...as a one-liner similar to this:

```
import {o: {a, b}} from 'lib'
```

The above statement throws `ES2015 named imports do not destructure. Use another statement for destructuring after the import.`

This is easy with `let {o: {a, b}} = require('lib')` but it seems impossible in ES6, correct?

Comment: It's not possible

Comment: that "behavior", `{foo} from 'myModule'`,  is already "assigned" for named imports, so therefore you cannot destructure it, even if the syntax is almost same. How would you differentiate it from each other? This has been requested/discussed for years.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I don't see why the differentiation is different though in this case than normal destructuring (e.g. the when using `require`). In case of a naming conflict, you'd have to rename it as usual: `let {o: {a: oa, b}, a} = require('lib')`

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible because it is forbidden by the ECMAscript specification

Comment: Any chance you know or had any idea what was the trade-off make it forbidden ? Just curious .

Comment: No idea, but you can look at the spec itself here: https://262.ecma-international.org/ or look through the old meeting minutes or email logs from when the spec was being debated